# Binary Classification using CNN but accuracy not increasing above 0.52 and validation accuracy is also constant at the 0.46

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

Working on a flood susceptibility mapping project .. using two classes flooded or non flooded data size take 35*35*16 here 16 number of channel used that are flood predictive features..

i have loaded the data built a simple leNet based model but the accuracy not increasing.. changed the image size, number of filter, size of filter, number of dense layer units.. but still getting same result.

```
NAME = "LeNet"


model = Sequential()
#Layer 1
#Conv Layer 1
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 4, 
                 kernel_size = 3, 
                 strides = 1, 
                 activation = 'relu', 
                 input_shape = (35,35,16)))
#Pooling layer 1
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = 2, strides = 1))

#add a droupout
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

#Layer 2
#Conv Layer 2
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 8, 
                 kernel_size = 3,
                 strides = 1,
                 activation = 'relu',
                 input_shape = (32,32,4)))
#Pooling Layer 2
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = 2, strides = 1))

#add a droupout
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

#Layer 3
#Conv Layer 3
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 16, 
                 kernel_size = 3,
                 strides = 1,
                 activation = 'relu',
                 input_shape = (24,24,8)))
#Pooling Layer 3
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = 2, strides = 1))

#add a droupout
model.add(Dropout(0.4))


#Flatten
model.add(Flatten())


#Layer 3
#Fully connected layer 1
model.add(Dense(units = 100, activation = 'relu'))

#add a droupout
model.add(Dropout(0.4))


#Layer 4
#Fully connected layer 2
model.add(Dense(units = 64, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))



#Layer 5
#Output Layer
model.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("LeNet.h5", monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=1)
early = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=20, verbose=1, mode='auto')

tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="logs/{}".format(NAME))

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])


model.summary()
```

[image]

please suggest how to increase the accuracy.. and where m doing wrong..

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using any activation functions, **your model is only capable of learning linear dependencies**. Changing model size and architecture will not change this fact.

Since the dataset probably has some features that have a more complex relationship towards the flood probability, your model can nnot utilize the dataset correctly.

I suggest adding a [ReLU activation function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/relu) right after each Dense Layer, this should give your model more degrees of freedom and result in better accuracy.

Check out [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression) if you need some help with the setup.